# Changing output statement in python

Tags: python

I have created the following code. Everything is correct besides my output statement. On the end of the x: array there is a 79 which stands for the number of iterations. I am trying to make a statement which uses

```
print("The number of iterations is", )
```

I tried to put iter_ct in there but it gave me an error. Looking for some help with making this adjustment, thanks!
    import numpy as np 
    from pprint import pprint
    from numpy import array, zeros, diag, diagflat, dot

```
def jacobi(A,b,N=100,x=None):
    """Solves the equation Ax=b via the Jacobi iterative method."""
    # Create an initial guess if needed                                                                       
    if x is None:
        x = zeros(len(A[0]))

    # Create a vector of the diagonal elements of A                                                                                                                                                
    # and subtract them from A                                                                                                                                                                     
    D = diag(A)
    R = A - diagflat(D)

    x_old = x
    error = 1.0     # Dummy value
    iter_ct = 0
    while error > 10 ** (-15):
        x = (b - dot(R, x_old)) / D
        error = np.linalg.norm(x - x_old)
        iter_ct += 1
        x_old = x
    return x, iter_ct

A = np.array([[3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],[1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0]])
b = np.array([1.0,1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
guess = np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])

sol, iter = jacobi(A,b,N=100,x=guess)

print ("A:")
pprint(A)

print ("b:")
pprint(b)

print ("x:")
pprint(sol)

print("It took",sol[1], "iterations.")
```

This is the current output I am getting now. Notice the 79 on the end of the x: array

```
A:
array([[3., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [1., 3., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 3., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1., 3., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 1., 3., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 3., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 3., 1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 3., 1., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 3., 1.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 3.]])
b:
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
x:
(array([0.27638191, 0.17085427, 0.21105528, 0.1959799 , 0.20100503,
   0.20100503, 0.1959799 , 0.21105528, 0.17085427, 0.27638191]),
 79)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `jacobi` function is returning a tuple `(x, iter_ct)` so if you want to just print `iter_ct` you could do it like so: `pprint(sol[1])`

Alternatively you could unpack the tuple when you return it:

```
sol, iter = jacobi(A,b,N=100,x=guess)
pprint(iter)
```

Comment: thank you that works perfectly! one more question, how could I take that 79 out of the output statement for the x: array?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning two values from your `jacobi` function - `return x, iter_ct`.  This is assigned into `sol`.

perhaps you could try:

```
sol, iter = jacobi(A,b,N=100,x=guess)
pprint(sol)
#pprint(iter)  - don't print the '79'
```

Comment: would you know how to take the 79 out of the output from the x array?

Comment: With the return like that (`sol, iter = ...`) the `97` is no longer in the array `sol`.  You could always do a `del(sol[1])`.

Comment: where would I put the del(x[1])?

Comment: Sorry I got confused by `x`.  Add `del(sol[1])` before you `pprint(sol)` - which you call `x`.

Comment: 'tuple' object doesn't support item deletion

Comment: ah yes, my-bad.  `sol = sol[1]`

Comment: should I put that before del(sol[1])?

Comment: could you edit that into your answer I am a little confused!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182306/discussion-between-kingsley-and-fr14).

Answer (score 1):

```
print("The number of iterations is {}".format(x[-1]))
```

Use the statement above after you've executed the function.

Comment: would you know how to take the 79 out of the output from the x array?

Comment: I am assuming this is how it should be: x[-1]